# Material-UI Select shows the wrong value: More explanation in the post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have these choices where user can choose Cup, Mug, and Case. The problem here is that if I'll choose Cup, the value shows "Mug". And if I'll choose "Mug", it will display "Case". What is wrong with the codes here?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [prod, setProd] = useState("");
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(0);
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setProd(event.target.value);
    console.log(prod);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={prod}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value="Cup">Cup</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Mug">Mug</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Case">Case</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-4g34r?file=/demo.js:0-1094

Comment: Your code looks fine. The value in your console.log is async so it display the it before the update

See :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately

Comment: @Clément Thank you. It does work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with you code, you're just using `console.log` in the *wrong* spot.

When listeners such as `onChange`'s function are invoked, their invocation is somehow controlled by React. Every DOM event in React is wrapped in a custom function which makes possible, among other things, using `setState` inside the listener.

In your case, when `setProd` is invoked, a **sync task** will be scheduled. This task's purpose is to synchronize the Fiber tree, which involves finding out what's changed and committing the new changes so that the results can be seen in the browser.
This **sync task** I mentioned earlier will start executing **after the listener has finished** executing - so, logging to the console after calling `setProd` will use the **old value**, not the one that has just been provided to `setProd`.

In order to set that, you can add another `console.log` that will print the value that you'd probably expect:

```js
console.warn("REAL VALUE: ", prod);

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setProd(event.target.value);
  console.log(prod);
};
```

To spice things up a little, you can add a `debugger;` keyword in the listener so that you can get a better understanding of what's going on there:

[image]

In the image above, the breakpoint is stopped at `console.log(prod)`. You can see in the bottom right corner the `syncQueue` which contains the task which is responsible for updating the fiber tree. It has been added there as a result of using `setProd`.

Also notice that after the listener finishes, `flushSyncCallbackQueue` will be invoked(it's in the `finally` block) and this will lead to executing tasks which are in `syncQueue`.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at your `hanldeChange`

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setProd(event.target.value);
    console.log(prod);
  };
```

In `consol.log(prod)` prod is the variable what `event.target.value` will be. What you are actually seeing in the output console is the previous state, because setProd hasn't re-rendered the UI in time for the `prod` to hold the `event.target.value` that you have selected in the UI.

If you want to see in the output console what value you have selected in the dropdown use console.log like this `console.log(event.target.value)`

You can take a look here for more information on the lifecycle of setState https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html